# Where is Samsung's SIM manager in '/system/app'?

Tags: samsung

My custom ROM's SIM manager is broken, so I have to replace it with the official one but when I install it, it says the package exists by the same name. I need to replace it manually in '/system/app' yet I failed to locate the folder.

Comment: Check here: `/system/priv-app/SimSettingMgr/SimSettingMgr.apk`  its name is `com.sec.android.app.simsettingmgr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very likely that this individual app doesn't exist, instead it is embedded within the setting app. However you can still create a SimSettingMgr folder and put your apk in there and push the folder to system/app or system/priv-app and reboot.